# How to call 2 web services after clicking button in android?

Tags: android, asp.net

I have an android application which is suppose to save a transaction in one database and update the balance in another database by calling 2 seperate web methods. My first web method is called but the second web method is not called.

AsyncTask code

```
  public class Transaction extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>
    {
        private String finalBalance1 = "", price1 = "", pName = "", pNric = "", pClass = "", sno = "";
        public Transaction(String price1, String pName, String pNric, String pClass, String sno, String finalBalance1)
        {
            super();
            this.finalBalance1 = Double.toString(finalBalance);
            this.price1 = Double.toString(sPrice);
            this.pName = sRA.studentName;
            this.pNric = sRA.studentNric;
            this.pClass = sRA.studentClass;
            this.sno = logger.stallNo;
        }
        @Override
          protected Boolean doInBackground (String...url)
          { 
            boolean good = true;

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://152.226.152.175/NCO/WebService.asmx/InsertStudentTransaction");
            try
            {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NRIC", pNric));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", pName));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Class", pClass));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StallNo", sno));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AmountSpent", price1));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream in = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

             } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                  good = false;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  good = false;
                }
                return good;
              }

        protected void onPostExecute (Boolean good)
          {
            if(good == true)
            {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://152.226.152.175/NCO/WebService.asmx/UpdateParticulars");
            try
            {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NRIC", pNric));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FixedAmount", finalBalance1));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", pName));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Class", pClass));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream in = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }


             } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                  good = false;
             }catch (IOException e) {
                  good = false;
             }
            }
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: use AsSync task and on post execute call another service..

Comment: use AsyncTask for HttpClient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use AsyncTask instead Thread here, By using two seperate AsyncTask, You can call second task in first one's onPostExecute() method.

Pls check this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I still very much not understand how to use it. Do I replace Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable() onwards?

Comment: yes,you should replace thread by AysncTask: `private class Task extends AsyncTask<xxx, xxx, xxx> {
     protected Long doInBackground(xxx... xxx) {//call first http service here}


     protected void onPostExecute(xxx xxx) {//call another service here}
 }`

Comment: Then how do I call it on the onclick method?

Comment: execute task like this:  task.execute(xxx);

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to check if the method is working anot, like receiving a response

Comment: You can return response data in doInBackground (return result); then deal with result in onPostExecute(xxx result). if request is failed, you can return null in doInBackground, and check if result is null in onPostExecute.

Comment: For now, I return this boolean called good. if there is a catch exception, good will be false, if there is no catch exception the good will be true. But I can't check if good is true or false in onPostExecute()

Comment: How a about add good as a field in Result type(in onPostExecute(Result result)), so you can return it in doInBackground?

Comment: Okay,right now my first web service is executed,but the second web service is not executed. I use onPostExecute(String...url), same as the first web service

Comment: Have you call task2.execute(..) in task1's onPostExecute(String...url)?

Comment: Yes.I have added the AsyncTask codes in the question, could you help me see if there is a mistake somewhere? And now it also has a network on main thread exception

Comment: I haven't see @Override above onPostExecute method.

Comment: Ahhh its okay,I released onPostExecute is executed on the main ui thread so I had to create another asynctask to execute.Thanks btw!